# Why can't I use the type `Show a => [Something -> a]`?

Tags: haskell

I have a record type say

```
data Rec {
    recNumber :: Int
  , recName :: String
  -- more fields of various types
}
```

And I want to write a `toString` function for Rec :

```
recToString :: Rec -> String
recToString r = intercalate "\t" $ map ($ r) fields
  where fields = [show . recNumber, show . recName]
```

This works. `fields` has type `[Rec -> String]`. But I'm lazy and I would prefer writing

```
recToString r = intercalate "\t" $ map (\f -> show $ f r) fields
  where fields = [recNumber, recName]
```

But this doesn't work. Intuitively I would say `fields` has type `Show a => [Rec -> a]` and this should be ok. But Haskell doesn't allow it.

I'd like to understand what is going on here. Would I be right if I said that in the first case I get a list of functions such that the 2 instances of show are actually not the same function, but Haskell is able to determine which is which at compile time (which is why it's ok).

```
[show . recNumber, show . recName]
   ^-- This is show in instance Show Number
                     ^-- This is show in instance Show String
```

Whereas in the second case, I only have one literal use of `show` in the code, and that would have to refer to multiple instances, not determined at compile time ?

```
map (\f -> show $ f r) fields
            ^-- Must be both instances at the same time
```

Can someone help me understand this ? And also are there workarounds or type system expansions that allow this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type signature doesn't say what you think it says.

This seems to be a common misunderstanding. Consider the function

```
foo :: Show a => Rec -> a
```

People frequently seem to think this means that "`foo` can return any type that it wants to, so long as that type supports `Show`". *It doesn't.*

What it *actually* means is that `foo` must be able to return *any possible type*, because **the caller** gets to choose what the return type should be.

A few moments' thought will reveal that `foo` actually cannot exist. There is no way to turn a `Rec` into *any possible type that can ever exist*. It can't be done.

People often try to do something like `Show a => [a]` to mean "a list of mixed types but they all have `Show`". That obviously doesn't work; this type *actually* means that the list elements can be any type, but they still have to be all the same.

What you're trying to do seems reasonable enough. Unfortunately, I think your first example is about as close as you can get. You *could* try using tuples and lenses to get around this. You *could* try using Template Haskell instead. But unless you've got a hell of a lot of fields, it's probably not even worth the effort.

Comment: It should be noted that `a` can't be *any* type, it is *constrained* to types satisfying `Show a`. In this case, that constraint doesn't make enough sense to mean anything. But other constraints do; for example, `pi :: Floating a => a`. `pi` can be instantiated to any `Floating`. Of course, that's cheating a bit, since the class requires you to define `pi`. But that's the idea. The constraints of a polymorphic value can provide sufficient information to construct the requested data for any instance.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I wasn't reading the type signature correctly. It's still hard not to think of Haskell classes as OO interfaces :)

Comment: @ARRG As I say, it seems to be a common misunderstanding. Once you realise that _the caller_ decides, things become clearer. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The type you actually want is not:

```
Show a => [Rec -> a]
```

Any type declaration with unbound type variables has an implicit `forall`. The above is equivalent to:

```
forall a. Show a => [Rec -> a]
```

This isn't what you wan't, because the `a` must be specialized to a single type for the entire list. (By the caller, to *any* one type they choose, as MathematicalOrchid points out.) Because you want the `a` of each element in the list to be able to be instantiated differently... what you are actually seeking is an existential type.

```
[exists a. Show a => Rec -> a]
```

You are wishing for a form of subtyping that Haskell does not support very well. The above syntax is not supported at all by GHC. You can use newtypes to sort of accomplish this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
newtype Showy = forall a. Show a => Showy a

fields :: [Rec -> Showy]
fields = [Showy . recNumber, Showy . recName]
```

But unfortunatley, that is just as tedious as converting directly to strings, isn't it?

---

I don't believe that lens is capable of getting around this particular weakness of the Haskell type system:

```
recToString :: Rec -> String
recToString r = intercalate "\t" $ toListOf (each . to fieldShown) fields
  where fields = (recNumber, recName)
        fieldShown f = show (f r)

-- error: Couldn't match type Int with [Char]
```

---

Suppose the fields *do* have the same type:

```
fields = [recNumber, recNumber]
```

Then it works, and Haskell figures out which show function instance to use at compile time; it doesn't have to look it up dynamically.

If you manually write out `show` each time, as in your original example, then Haskell can determine the correct instance for each call to `show` at compile time.

As for existentials... it depends on implementation, but presumably, the compiler cannot determine which instance to use statically, so a dynamic lookup will be used instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'm really intrigued by the relationship between lexical occurences of show and what the compiler is or is not able to do because of it. I guess I'll have to come back to this once I'm more confortable with the type system in general.

Comment: That `newtype` looks unlikely. Doesn't that need to be `data`, to hold the dictionary?

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed it does. Although `newtype` currently doesn't even support an existential type without a class, either. I remember it was suggested at some point but discarded as not worth supporting. EDIT: Oh [the ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1965) has been reopened, maybe we'll see it eventually.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I've never been too comfortable with the peculiar mix of purposes of `newtype`. Aside from magical pattern matching, `data Foo a = Foo !a` should be the same as `newtype Foo a = Foo a`, but in fact their runtime representations are different.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest something very simple instead:

```
recToString r = intercalate "\t" [s recNumber, s recName]
  where s f = show (f r)
```

Answer (score 2):

All the elements of a list in Haskell must have the same type, so a list containing one `Int` and one `String` simply cannot exist. It is possible to get around this in GHC using existential types, but you probably shouldn't (this use of existentials is widely considered an anti-pattern, and it doesn't tend to perform terribly well). Another option would be to switch from a list to a tuple, and use some weird stuff from the `lens` package to map over both parts. It might even work.